# VBA get HTML Document

Tags: javascript, vba

The below code fetches the original HTML document and not the one after running the javascript. Please advise...

```
Sub test_extract()

  Dim ie As InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

  Set ie = New InternetExplorer
  ie.navigate "http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/results.aspx?Code=532540&Company=TCS&qtr=85.00&RType=c"

  ie.Visible = True
  Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

 ie.navigate "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkDetailed','')"
 'Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop 
 'This loop never ends hence using application.wait
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

 Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

 ie.Quit
 Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
 Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_extract()

  Dim ie As InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

  Set ie = New InternetExplorer
  ie.navigate "http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/results.aspx?Code=532540&Company=TCS&qtr=85.00&RType=c"

  ie.Visible = True
  Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

  Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
  HTMLdoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload").Click

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

 ie.Quit
 Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
 Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Diego. I want the page to navigate to    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDetailed"    and then extract the HTML document. The code still returns the old document.